# passing a variable to a dict in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following simple code:

```
dataStore = {}

def addLocationToDataStore(location):
    dataStore = {location: {'teamChatMessageCount.staff': 0, 'privateChatMessageCount.staff': 0, 'callCount.staff': 0, 'meetingCount.staff': 0, 'meetingsOrganizedCount.staff': 0, 'adHocMeetingsOrganizedCount.staff': 0, 'adHocMeetingsAttendedCount.staff': 0, 'urgentMessages.staff': 0, 'postMessages.staff': 0, 'replyMessages.staff': 0, 'audioDuration.staff': 0, 'videoDuration.staff': 0, 'screenShareDuration.staff': 0,
                            'teamChatMessageCount.student': 0, 'privateChatMessageCount.student': 0, 'callCount.student': 0, 'meetingCount.student': 0, 'meetingsOrganizedCount.student': 0, 'adHocMeetingsOrganizedCount.student': 0, 'adHocMeetingsAttendedCount.student': 0, 'urgentMessages.student': 0, 'postMessages.student': 0, 'replyMessages.student': 0, 'audioDuration.student': 0, 'videoDuration.student': 0, 'screenShareDuration.student': 0}}
    

addLocationToDataStore("test") 

print(datastore)
```

The intent is to create a nested dictionary when addLocationToDataStore is called. The function will work if i hard code the location variable, but not if i'm using is as a key.

I was looking at if i needed to use ' around the location (as per below) but that isn't working either (illegal character)

```
datastore = {\'location\': {
```

How do i escape it or utilise the dictionary a little more dynamically?

Comment: wondering if i should serialise the string first

Answer (score 0):

i was being a little silly with this, its a syntax error and should be the following.

```
 dataStore[location] = {'teamChatMessageCount.staff': 0
```

Comment: you can use `dataStore.get(location, None)`, that way you won't get an error even when your key does not exist in the dictionary.